# jQuery Validation not working, No errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form to submit property details, I use the jquery validation library.
I need to validate the form with the jquery validation library and send the values to my php file called submit-property-data.php for inserting into my database.

Once i click the submit button I can't see any validation errors also no errors in console.

I want to validate the form first and send the data to my php file to process the values.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#notification").hide();

  /* handling form validation */
  $("#property-form").validate({
    rules: {
      prop_title: "required",
      prop_price: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
        },
      prop_area: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
      prop_address: "required",
      prop_message: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 2000
      },
      prop_owner_name: "required",
      prop_owner_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      prop_owner_phone: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      'prop_title': {
        required: "Please enter title for your property"
      },
      prop_price: {
        required: "Please enter price of your property",
        digits: "Please enter price in digits (AED)"
      },
      prop_area: "Please enter Sqft of your property",
      prop_address: "Please enter address of your property",
      prop_message: {
        required: "Please enter detailed Information",
        minlength: "Please enter something about your property in 50 - 20000 characters",
        maxlength: "Please enter something about your property in 50 - 20000 characters"
      },
    },
    submitHandler: submitPropertyForm
  });
  
  /* Handling login functionality */
  function submitPropertyForm() {
    var data = $("#property-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'submit_property_data.php',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#submit-button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sendving ...');
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == "ok") {
          console.log(1);
          document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
          $("#notification").html('<b> ' + response + ' !</b>').show();
          //setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; ',4000);
        } else {
          $("#notification").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $("#notification").html('<b>' + response + ' !</b>').fadeOut();
            $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Send');
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-area-7 submit-property">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- <div id="error_message" class="notification-box"></div> -->
      </div>
      <div id="notification" class="notification-box"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="submit-address">
          <form name="property-form" method="post" id="property-form">
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Tell Me</span> Something About Your Property</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="search-contents-sidebar mb-30">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Property Title</label>
                <input class="input-text" name="prop_title" id="prop_title" placeholder="Property Title">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Status</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="prop_status" name="prop_status">
                      <option value="Sale">For Sale</option>
                      <option value="Rent">For Rent</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="prop_title" name="prop_type">
                      <option value="Modern">Modern</option>
                      <option value="Traditional">Traditional</option>
                      <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price (Dirham)</label>
                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_price" id="prop_price" placeholder="AED">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Sqft</label>
                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_area" id="prop_area" placeholder="SqFt">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Bed Rooms</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="prop_rooms" id="prop_rooms">
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Bathroom</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Location</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-30 ">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Address</label>
                  <input class="input-text" id="prop_address" name="prop_address" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Upload</span> Photos Of Villa </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone dropzone-design mb-10">
              <div class="dz-default dz-message" data=""><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Detailed</span> Information</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-30">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="input-text" id="prop_message" name="prop_message" placeholder="Detailed Information"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="row mb-30">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Building Age <span>(optional)</span></label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="years">
                          <option>0-1 Years</option>
                          <option>0-5 Years</option>
                          <option>0-10 Years</option>
                          <option>0-20 Years</option>
                          <option>0-40 Years</option>
                          <option>40+Years</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Bedrooms (optional)</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Bathrooms (optional)</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <label class="margin-t-10">Features (optional)</label>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_parking" name="opt_parking" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox1">
                                  Free Parking
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_air_condition" name="opt_air_condition" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox2">
                                  Air Condition
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_seat" name="opt_seat" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox3">
                                  Places to seat
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_swimming" name="opt_swimming" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox4">
                                  Swimming Pool
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_laundary" name="opt_laundary" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox5">
                                  Laundry Room
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_window_covering" name="opt_window_covering" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox6">
                                  Window Covering
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_parking" name="opt_parking" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox7">
                                  Central Heating
                              </label>
                          </div>
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="checkbox8" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox8">
                                  Alarm
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>-->
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Contact</span> Details</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_name" id="prop_owner_name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_email" id="prop_owner_email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Contact No</label>
                  <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_phone" id="prop_owner_phone" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="button" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: put `$("#property-form").validate(..` in a function say `validateForm` and call it on `submit-button` click event. it will return true or false based on validations success status based on which you call `submitPropertyForm` function

Comment: Your version of jQuery and the jQuery Validate plugin are really old.  You should consider using the newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

1. You're using an old version of jquery.
2. You should add a event trigger to check when the form is submitted, like this:

`$("#submit-button").bind('click', function() {... }`

From jQuery 1.7 you can use 'on' instead

`$("#submit-button").on('click', function() {... }`

3. Finally, use the valid() method to check if the form is valid before running the submitPropertyForm() function:

```
if ( $("#property-form").valid() ) {
        submitPropertyForm();
    } else {
        console.log('form invalid');
    }
})
```

Comment: The form producing validation errors. But when i enter some values but if i click directly to submit button without inputing any field it not showing any validation errors.

Comment: Yea, it worked :) The issue with my js file that i put head ?, We need to put at bottom?

Comment: In fact, you included jquery and jquery.validate.min.js at the top of your file, but there was no reference to your own 'property.js' file. Since your code didn't have the entire html file, I just assumed you just hadn't copy/pasted that bit and I added it to the bottom of the html file. Feel free to upvote ;-)

Comment: Let me know how i can change the error message color in that form ?, I already have a class called .error with red color but it not affecting in this form but it working in my contact form ?

Comment: @phpfranko if I add a class .error which has { color: red } it shows up fine in the form on the errors. If it's not showing for you, I suspect you may not have the css loaded OK.

Comment: Your `click` handler does not need to be that complicated.  Just run `.valid()` and the plugin handles the rest automatically.  See:  https://jsfiddle.net/up9snmdv/

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your form does not contain a `type="submit"` `button` or `input`.  The plugin automatically captures the `submit` button as long as it's the correct `type`.  Since your submit button is a `type="button"`, it's completely ignored.

**Simply change `type` into `"submit"`** and your demo works.

```
<button type="submit" ....
```

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#notification").hide();

  /* handling form validation */
  $("#property-form").validate({
    rules: {
      prop_title: "required",
      prop_price: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
        },
      prop_area: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
      prop_address: "required",
      prop_message: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 2000
      },
      prop_owner_name: "required",
      prop_owner_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      prop_owner_phone: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      'prop_title': {
        required: "Please enter title for your property"
      },
      prop_price: {
        required: "Please enter price of your property",
        digits: "Please enter price in digits (AED)"
      },
      prop_area: "Please enter Sqft of your property",
      prop_address: "Please enter address of your property",
      prop_message: {
        required: "Please enter detailed Information",
        minlength: "Please enter something about your property in 50 - 20000 characters",
        maxlength: "Please enter something about your property in 50 - 20000 characters"
      },
    },
    submitHandler: submitPropertyForm
  });
  
  /* Handling login functionality */
  function submitPropertyForm() {
    var data = $("#property-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'submit_property_data.php',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#submit-button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sendving ...');
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == "ok") {
          console.log(1);
          document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
          $("#notification").html('<b> ' + response + ' !</b>').show();
          //setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; ',4000);
        } else {
          $("#notification").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $("#notification").html('<b>' + response + ' !</b>').fadeOut();
            $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Send');
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-area-7 submit-property">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- <div id="error_message" class="notification-box"></div> -->
      </div>
      <div id="notification" class="notification-box"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="submit-address">
          <form name="property-form" method="post" id="property-form">
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Tell Me</span> Something About Your Property</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="search-contents-sidebar mb-30">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Property Title</label>
                <input class="input-text" name="prop_title" id="prop_title" placeholder="Property Title">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Status</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="prop_status" name="prop_status">
                      <option value="Sale">For Sale</option>
                      <option value="Rent">For Rent</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="prop_title" name="prop_type">
                      <option value="Modern">Modern</option>
                      <option value="Traditional">Traditional</option>
                      <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price (Dirham)</label>
                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_price" id="prop_price" placeholder="AED">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Sqft</label>
                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_area" id="prop_area" placeholder="SqFt">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Bed Rooms</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="prop_rooms" id="prop_rooms">
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Bathroom</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Location</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-30 ">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Address</label>
                  <input class="input-text" id="prop_address" name="prop_address" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Upload</span> Photos Of Villa </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone dropzone-design mb-10">
              <div class="dz-default dz-message" data=""><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Detailed</span> Information</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-30">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="input-text" id="prop_message" name="prop_message" placeholder="Detailed Information"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="row mb-30">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Building Age <span>(optional)</span></label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="years">
                          <option>0-1 Years</option>
                          <option>0-5 Years</option>
                          <option>0-10 Years</option>
                          <option>0-20 Years</option>
                          <option>0-40 Years</option>
                          <option>40+Years</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Bedrooms (optional)</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Bathrooms (optional)</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <label class="margin-t-10">Features (optional)</label>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_parking" name="opt_parking" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox1">
                                  Free Parking
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_air_condition" name="opt_air_condition" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox2">
                                  Air Condition
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_seat" name="opt_seat" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox3">
                                  Places to seat
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_swimming" name="opt_swimming" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox4">
                                  Swimming Pool
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_laundary" name="opt_laundary" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox5">
                                  Laundry Room
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_window_covering" name="opt_window_covering" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox6">
                                  Window Covering
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="opt_parking" name="opt_parking" value="1" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox7">
                                  Central Heating
                              </label>
                          </div>
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                              <input id="checkbox8" type="checkbox">
                              <label for="checkbox8">
                                  Alarm
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>-->
            <div class="main-title-2">
              <h1><span>Contact</span> Details</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_name" id="prop_owner_name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_email" id="prop_owner_email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Contact No</label>
                  <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_phone" id="prop_owner_phone" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively for whatever reason, if you want a `type="button"` or use some other trigger, you'll need to write a `click` handler that calls the `.valid()` method...

```
$("#submit-button").click(function() {
    $("#property-form").valid(); // trigger validation programmatically 
});
```

**DEMO 2**:  [jsfiddle.net/5ytjakvz/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/5ytjakvz/1/)

For ***newer*** versions of jQuery, use the `.on()` method...

```
$("#submit-button").on('click', function() { ....
```